# Differential equations. Help with three examples, substitutions...

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y'=2 ({{y+2}\over{x+y-1}})^2$$
$$(y'+1)ln{{y+x}\over{x+3}}={{y+x}\over{x+3}}$$
$$y'={y+2\over x+1}+tg{y-2x\over x+1}$$

Now these assignments are in a group in which the answer is come upon by using the substitution $z={y\over x }$ or $y'={a_1x+b_1y+c_1\over a_2x+b_2y+c_2}$ is solved by($x_1,x_2$-answers to the the system(for x and y respectively)$\begin {cases}a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0\\a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0\end {cases}$ then the answer is computed $$\begin {cases}1.)a_1b_2-a_2b_1\neq0; x=x_1+u,y=x_2+v\\ 2.)a_1b_2-a_2b_1=0; z=a_1x+b_1y \end {cases} $$ For 1.) x, y are plugged into the equation, and you would get a substitution there after quickly sorting $z={y\over x}$ Both 1.) and 2.) become solvable by integration there after...

Comment: How to solve these equations is the question, because i cant seem to do it..

Comment: Upvote my question because it took effort go put out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}=\frac{y+2}{(x-3)+(y+2)},\qquad\frac{x+y}{x+3}=\frac{(x+3)+(y-3)}{x+3}
$$